# Firebase database security rules and dollar signs

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a Google docs type of app where multiple users can edit a `document` in real-time.

These are my security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "docs": {
      "$doc_id": {
          ".read": "auth.token.doc_id === $doc_id",
          ".write": "auth.token.doc_id === $doc_id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my Auth token payload (example)

```
{
  "provider": "anonymous",
  "uid": "e71afdf1-2b31-4c75-8f10-a9b0f916915e",
  "token": {
    "doc_id": 11
  }
}
```

So when I try to read this path `/docs/11/data` I get a `Simulated read denied` error.

On the other hand when I put this rule instead

```
".read": "auth.token.doc_id === 11",  (i.e. hard code $doc_id as 11)
```

The read passes.

But isn't `$doc_id` equal to `11` when I read `/docs/11/data` or am I misunderstanding something?

P.S. In case it matters, here is the data inside my database

```
{
  "docs": {
    "2": {
      "data": {
        "title": "test"
      }
    },
    "11": {
      "data": {
        "title": "test"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, can you share the minimal rules that reproduce where you got stuck? If you're having a problem making a specific call in your code match with the security rules, also share the minimal code that reproduces the failure.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm taking a different approach to it. What i'm basically doing now is using the REST API to update the rules of `{"projects":{"1":".read"...}` every time someone adds a username. Also I'm authenticating via PHP using `createCustomToken` too. So basically the read/write rule inside each project node is `auth.token.username == username1 || auth.token.username == username2` (the rule I'm setting via PHP using the firebase REST API). Will let you know how it works out.. Thanks.

Comment: If you have more of the details I asked for, add them to your question by clicking the edit link under it.

Comment: Hi, never mind I figured it out.. I was using === instead of == so it was failing. I guess the key is string while my auth.token was a number. I've changed it and it is working now! Thanks still